# Buscar valor en dataframe y, cuando lo encuentre, buscar un texto concreto en ese mismo dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe en el cual tengo que buscar el contenido de un columna dentro de un rango de ese mismo dataframe. Y, cuando encuentre ese valor, necesito buscar un texto concreto para devolver el contenido de la siguiente columna.

Me explico mejor con un ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi dataframe (no es el original, sino que he ocultado columnas). Necesito buscar el contenido de la columna 'Child Name 1' en las columnas "Related Name 1", "Related Name 2", .. , "Related Name 30" (en el original hay hasta 30). Si no lo encuentra, tengo que, tomando el contenido de la columna 'Child Name 2', buscar ese contenido en las mismas columnas de antes, es decir, en 'Related Name 1', etc. También hay hasta 18 niveles (cada nivel incluye las columnas Child Name, Status e ID. Hay 7 más, pero las he ocultado). Había pensado en definir dos rangos y recorrerlos con un bucle FOR (incluyo el rango original), pero entiendo que el valor de Python es no usar este tipo de loops.
Cuando encuentre ese valor, tengo que verificar que la columna Subject tengo el valor 'International' (es decir, si el valor se encuentra en Related Name 2, tengo que verificar que Subject 2 tiene ese valor) y guardar en un dataframe nuevo el valor que contiene MRC correspondiente (en el ejemplo anterior, MRC 2).

```py
for i in df.iloc[:,29:107]:
    for j in df.iloc[:,290:587]:
        if df[df[i].isin(df[j]).any(1)]: 
            //Encuentra el valor 'International' más próximo..
            //Añade ese valor a un nuevo dataframe
```

Disculpad pero, soy bastante nuevo en Python y después de pelearme un par de días con diferentes métodos, no he conseguido nada.

¿Me podéis dar alguna idea sobre cómo afrontar este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, ¿El valor de `Child Name 1` lo buscas en la misma fila en las otras columnas? ¿O se tiene que buscar en todas las filas de las otras columnas? ¿Puedes agregar a tu pregunta por lo menos 10 líneas de tus datos para hacer pruebas?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Cómo puedo añadir 10 filas de mi dataframe? Disculpa la ignorancia. Por otra parte, únicamente hay que buscar en una fila. Cada fila es independiente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) y [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) para hacer la búsqueda y agregar una nueva columna para saber si está o no.

```
df["Child Name 1 exist"] = df.drop("Child Name 1", 1).isin(df["Child Name 1"]).any(1)
df["Child Name 2 exist"] = df.drop("Child Name 2", 1).isin(df["Child Name 2"]).any(1)
```

**Explicación:**

Con `drop()` "quitas" (La excluyes) la columna del `dataframe`

Con `isin()` revisa si existe en el dataframe

Con `any()` revisas que haya por lo menos una coincidencia

Luego puedes utilizar el resultado para buscar en la columna `Subject` si es internacional o no

**Edición:**

Para obtener en otra columna el nombre de todas las columnas donde aparece la coincidencia puedes utilizar `apply()`

```
df['Name1 exist in col']=df.drop("Child Name 1", 1).isin(df["Child Name 1"]).apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index.tolist() , axis=1)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Mañana intento lo que me comentas y te comento. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué funciona me recomiendas para devolver la posición de la columna donde encuentra la coincidencia? ¿Debo usar 'where' por ejemplo?

Comment: @Alex, edité mi respuesta y agregué esa parte, como no sé si solo aparezca una coincidencia o varias el código crea una lista con los nombres de todas las columnas donde aparezca la conicidencia

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato. Solo aparece una vez en esa fila. Entiendo que, quitando el método tolist, devuelve el índice donde se encuentra el valor coincidente. Sin embargo, me sale un error: KeyError: "['Child Name 1'] not found in axis". No lo entiendo porque hemos incluido axis = 1 para indicar a pandas que use columnas en lugar de filas.. ¿alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, `axis = 1` es para indicar que buscamos en columnas. Si quitas el método `tolist()` va a devolver una serie. Si te dice `['Child Name 1'] not found in axis` revisa el nombre de tus columnas, yo lo hice de acuerdo a la información de tu pregunta pero como no agregaste datos es posible que el nombre de la columna tenga espacios al final que no se vean, revisa como está el nombre.

Comment: Totalmente correcto.. un espacio provocaba el error. Sin embargo, ahora me devuelve el siguiente:  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: ¿Qué cambiaste del código que yo puse?

Comment: Gracias. No tengo ni idea qué podía estar provocando el error pero, copié y pegué el código de nuevo y ya veo la columna que devuelve la etiqueta de la columna.. Ahora trabajaré en el código que permita, dado el valor anterior, encontrar el siguiente valor 'International' en Subject (digo el siguiente porque puede haber más de uno en esa fila). Lo intento y te comento cualquier duda. Gracias!!

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: Hola , tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar los valores de esa columna que hemos creado, ya que esta es una lista y, al utilizar index.get_loc con un bucle for para buscar un valor basado en el contenido de la lista, me devuelve el siguiente error, ya que entiendo que no encuentra la columna con ese nombre, al estar contenido entre brackets:  '['Child Name 2']' is an invalid key. Estoy buscando la forma de sustituir esos brackets, pero al ser una lista, no me funciona la función replace, por ejemplo. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Buen día, por favor crea una nueva pregunta con toda la información y el código que tienes, marca la parte donde te da el error y ponme el link en un comentario y lo checo con gusto. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias y disculpa!